# Serial devices ttyS ttyM difference

Tags: linux, rhel, drivers, serial-port

What is the difference between `ttyS` and `ttyM` serial devices?

Can they both be configured through `setserial` and `ttys`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ttyS` is the original "standard" serial device; `ttyM` is newer (not the only serial device).  The [`MAKEDEV`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man8/MAKEDEV.8.html) manual page summarizes the listing (originally in Linux Documentation/drivers.txt, but now in other places as the ["Linux Allocated Devices List"](https://static.lwn.net/kerneldoc/admin-guide/devices.html)):

```
SERIAL DEVICES

       ttyS{0..63}
              Standard  serial  ports.  There  is  no  group keyword, you must
              specify these individually. However ttyS{0..3} are created under
              the generic option for most architectures.
```

and

```
       PAM or ttyM
              Creates PAM multimodem (or ISI serial card) ports ttyM{0..15}.
```

A quick look around would show that people do use `setserial` with `ttyM`...